# How do I rewrite this code to avoid using the global?

Tags: c++, namespaces, scope, global

I am writing some routines that directly interface with our design group's hardware.  I'll try to explain this scenario as succinctly as possible.

Our hardware generates various types of interrupts to the embedded CPU that runs the firmware I am describing.  Due to the nature of our debugging plan, sometimes we want to limit the number of interrupts that are serviced.  This interrupt limit is passed into the running firmware via an external register interface.

SO!  I have two functions: `inthandler()` and `limit_interrupts()`.  They basically look like this:

in file interrupt_handler.cpp:

```
void inthandler(){
    if (num_ints_serviced < int_limit)
    { 
        ...handle interrupt...
        num_ints_serviced++;
    }
}
```

in file external_command_handler.cpp:

```
void limit_interrupts(){
    int_limit = <read int limit from external register>;
}
```

Currently, I have `int_limit` and `num_ints_serviced` declared as global variables.  I would like to know if there's a way to avoid using globals for this.

I have a vague idea of how to do this:

- Declare `num_ints_serviced` as a static int, so that its value doesn't get reset every time that `inthandler()` is called.  (However, this brings up another issue because at some point in our testing, we do want to reset that counter to 0. Currently it's just a matter of calling another function, `reset_in_counter()` that modifies the global.)
- Somehow mess with the scope of `int_limit` so that it can be declared locally within interrupt_handler.cpp but modified from external_command_handler.cpp.  Maybe using namespaces?  I'm not sure about the particulars.

I know best practices says you should avoid using globals, but they have *some* uses.  I wonder if this is just one of those uses, and maybe I'm just making this problem too difficult (after all, using globals is working for this case).

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
void inthandler() {
    static int limit = limit_interrupts();
    static int n = 0;
    if (n++ < limit) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But you probably want some way to reset n, which this doesn't provide, and it also only allows for setting the limit once, the first time the method is called.

Comment: So in this example, what would lmit_interrupts() look like?  something like this? int limit_interrrupts(){static int limit = 0; limit = <external read>; return limit;}

Comment: it will be the same as it is now, because it only gets called once in inthandler.

Comment: the thing is that the interrupt limit can change on-the-fly in our testing.  Without powering down hardware, we want to be able to dynamically increase the number of interrupts we want firmware to handle.  So that information needs to get saved off somewhere.

Comment: then don't make the call to limit_interrupts() go to a static.

Answer (score 1):

Many people will not agree with me but here's my take on it.

If what you're representing is in fact a global then it should be represented as a global in your program.

- This information represents properties of the CPU
- You only have one (CPU)
- You are never likely to have more than one without a redesign (and therefore a code refactor)
- There is little to be gained by making the program flexible enough to handle multiple CPU configurations. It will be slower, larger, more error prone, and harder to debug.

It's legitimately a global unless one of my assumptions is wrong.